# Set pattern for two chars

Tags: jquery, maskedtextbox, maskedinput

I am Using Jquery masked plungin to set timer input like HH:MM.

I would like to set minutes which allows only 00,25,50 and 75.

I'm using translation pattern , but it allows to set pattern for only single chars,not for both MM jointly.

Any idea how to achieve it?